# How to connect solid connected pieces?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

[image]

Simple question, how do I make this one piece?

Ive tried all the pathfinder options, and it does not connect the pieces, same as compound shape.

I'm stuck trying to do this the hard way, there has got to be some easy way of connecting all this as one piece.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is frustrating me.

-Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see exactly how your shapes are set up from the image, it looks like the bottom part is constructed differently from the main letter.

Regardless, Pathfinder is the correct way to go. What you need to do first is outline your strokes. Pathfinder doesn't play well (or at all) with strokes. Just do (Object > Expand) on your shapes first.

Answer (score 0):

Like Cai said, outline your strokes first either the way he suggested or (Object > Path > Outline Stroke).

For the solid black pieces, zoom in extremely close and make sure the anchor points are either perfectly aligned or, preferably, overlapping.

With Pathfinder, groups can cause a lot of headache. Ungroup (Object > Ungroup) any shapes that might be grouped before running a Pathfinder operation.

Answer (score 0):

- Select all
- Menu: Object > Expand Appearance (if available)
- Menu: Object > Expand
- Pathfinder Panel : Merge Button.